# Is it possible to configure TFLite to return a model with bias quantized to int8?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, quantization, tensorflow-lite, cmsis

I'm working with Keras/Tensorflow to develop an ANN that will be deployed to a low-end MCU. For this purpose, I have quantized the original ANN using the post-training quantization mechanism offered by Tensorflow Lite. If the weights are indeed quantized to int8, biases were converted from float to int32. Considering that I pretend to implement this ANN in CMSIS-NN, this is a problem as they only support int8 and int16 data.

Is it possible to configure TF Lite to also quantize biases to int8? Below follows the code I am executing:

```
def quantizeToInt8(representativeDataset):
    # Cast the dataset to float32
    data = tf.cast(representativeDataset, tf.float32)
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data)).batch(1)

    # Generator function that returns one data point per iteration
    def representativeDatasetGen():
        for inputValue in data:
            yield[inputValue]
    
    # ANN quantization
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("C:/Users/miguel/Documents/Universidade/PhD/Code_Samples/TensorFlow/originalModel.h5")

    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    converter.representative_dataset = representativeDatasetGen
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]
    converter.inference_type = tf.int8
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
    tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()

    return tflite_quant_model
```

Comment: It's not possible to configure TFLite to do that. Biases are intentionally int32 otherwise the quantization accuracy would not be good. In order to make this work, you'd have to add a new op or custom op and then come up with a custom quantization tooling all together. Do you have any other workaround, eg: another MCU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Comments

> It's not possible to configure `TFLite` to do that. `Biases` are
> intentionally `int32` otherwise the quantization accuracy would not be
> good. In order to make this work, you'd have to add a new op or custom
> op and then come up with a custom quantization tooling all together.(paraphrased from
> Meghna Natraj).